# Need free db2 (mainframe) query tool

Tags: db2, zos

I thought TOAD Freeware would be a good choice, but it doesn't support ZOS (mainframe?) connections, only the paid version.

Suggestions for a alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [SquirrelSQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/), a free, Java-based SQL query tool which works really well for DB2.  It has a DB2 add-in as well. If you need any help getting started, let me know.

Comment: That uses standard DB2 JDBC drivers so won't work without the high end (expensive) versions of DB2 Connect.

Comment: @paxdiablo - My bad; didn't realize that DB2 on the mainframe doesn't have native support for ODBC connections.

Comment: I think I have db2 connect. I'll try it.

Comment: @Chad - in your ODBC Data Source Administrator (Control Panel->Admin tools->Data Sources (ODBC)->Drivers tab), do you have IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER listed?

Comment: @transistor1: Yep, I am having trouble trying to connect using Squirrell

Comment: @Chad - I'm not on my work computer now so I can walk you through it tomorrow. My guess is that you probably have to create a DSN for your data source first (or know which one is your existing connection). You can do this in the ODBC connections dialog that I mentioned above. The "hard" part in Squirrel SQL is finding the right connection string for your Alias. For now, check the "Using SQuirreL" section of [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0312bhogal/), which should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Initial comment: In Squireell in my driver section, Ithe IDM DB2 App and Net driver have a red "X" next to them. only JDBC has a checkbox. Not sure why. I do have the IBM DB2 driver installer...

Comment: Hi @Chad - I posted a [photoset on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/10385005@N00/sets/72157627434970199/) describing how I have my ODBC drivers and SquirrelSQL set up. Start from the first one and read the notes on each pic. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It looks like a good tool. I will check it out more fully later.

Comment: I've been playing around with it, it looks like a really nice utility.

Comment: Any time! Glad to help if I can. I'm happy it's useful to you.

Comment: @transistor1, I am trying to get Squirell working on Win7 now (XP worked fine) and now the JDBC Driver even has an "X" next to it. I feel like it originally had a check, but I could be wrong. What do I have to do to get that Driver properly installed?

Comment: I haven't tried it under Win 7 -- Im still on XP on the machine where I have Squirrel installed. Did you go through that Flikr photoset I had posted? One snag might be if you have a 64 bit machine, there are 2 odbc dialogs - a 64 bit one (c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe) and a 32 bit one (c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe). Which one you add dsns to depends on whether the app that's using it is 64-bit or 32 bit. If in doubt, configure both.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be *very* unlikely to get this without a paid version. IBM guards its mainframe data very well.

For example, while the standard DB2 Connect clients ship with `db2jcc_licence_cu.jar`, that's the Cloudscape and LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows) license.

To connect to the mainframe, you need `db2jcc_licence_cisuz.jar` (for Cloudscape, iSeries, SQLJ, LUW and z/OS). And that only ships with high end versions of DB2 Connect.

Comment: FYI. I did get it to work against a mainframe on Win XPP. Now I am having difficulties trying to get the JDBC Driver recognized on Win 7